# Button is visible while page is opening

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a very simple xaml: (I only added a button to the basic app template)

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    IsTabStop="false"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:common="using:App1.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>

        <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
        <x:String x:Key="AppName">My Application</x:String>
    </Page.Resources>

    <!--
        This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
        * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
        * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
    -->
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Back button and page title -->
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
        </Grid>

        <!-- HERE IS THE BUTTON-->
        <Button Opacity="0" Margin="110,153,0,169" Grid.Row="1" Height="306" Width="476"/>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

                <!-- The entire page respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PortraitBackButtonStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>

                <!-- The back button and title have different styles when snapped -->
                <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedBackButtonStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="pageTitle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

My problem is that, although I've set the opacity of the button to 0, it is visible during the short animation when my app opens.

How can I make it invisible while the page is opening?

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses That's not a property of `Button`

Comment: it is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.aspx

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses That's `System.Windows.Controls.Button`. In windows 8 it's[`Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.button.aspx#properties).

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses Oh, wow. I tried using `Visibility="Collapsed"` and it worked. Thanks. :) Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir, you need to use `Visibility` and set it to `Collapsed`

So,

```
    <Button Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0" Margin="110,153,0,169" Grid.Row="1" Height="306" Width="476"/>
```

according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.visibility.aspx)